# Retorno undefined - .getJSON+ .each

Tags: javascript

Estou com um problema quando faço uma busca no json e percorro, a busca é feita corretamente consigo percorrer o objeto normalmente, porem ao retornar (return) "undefined" para a variavel na qual a funcao foi chamada

1. O "**row['valor']**" é chamada com o valor de uma tabela esta capturando corretamente.
2. O "**$.getJSON('/filas/slctTipo'** ... " busca na base e retorna o JSON abaixo.

```
[
 {"id": 1, "tipo": "Marcar consulta"}, 
 {"id": 2, "tipo": "Remarcar consulta"}, 
 {"id": 3, "tipo": "Desmarcar consulta"}, 
 {"id": 4, "tipo": "informacoes"}
]
```

```
function conv(v){
  console.log('CHEGA NA FUNC -> ' + v)
  $.getJSON('/filas/slctTipo', function(result){
    var teste =''
    $.each(result, function(key, val){

      if(v == val.id){
        teste = val.tipo
        console.log("CLOG01 -> " + teste)
        return teste
      }
      //console.log("CLOG02 -> " + teste)
      // return(teste)
    });
     console.log("CLOG03 -> " + teste)
    //return teste
  });
}

function detailObs(index, row) {
  console.log("ID -> " + row['valor'])
  html = conv(row['valor'])
  console.log("VARhtm -> " + html)
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O `each` não está iterando sobre o objeto, mas sim sobre o array que contém os objetos. Parece-me que você precisará de dois `$.each`: um para o array (_top-level_) e outro para iterar sobre as chaves e valores de cada um dos objetos contidos nesse array.

Comment: fiz um console.log no "result" e retorna
Objetos ->[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
e CLOG1 ele acha a info correta. queria so retornar essa info. funciona no debug mas no return não.

Comment: Vc comentou a linha `//return teste`. Desta forma a função não está retornando nada, por isso dá `undefined` em `html = conv(row['valor'])`. E mesmo que vc descomente a linha citada, iria retornar vazio, pois `var teste =''`. A linha `html = conv(row['valor'])` não vai esperar _returns_ que estão dentro do `each`. Ou seja, `conv(row['valor'])` requer um valor naquele instante da execução e não vai esperar o processamento do `each`, aí retorna `undefined`.

Comment: de fato o retun da funcao tava comentada, mas naoconsigo passar o valor p/ ele.

Comment: `conv` não tem valor de retorno, quem retorna `teste` é o callback que vc passou para `$.getJSON()` e além disso, pela ordem em que é invocado `console.log`, `$.getJSON()` é assíncrono e vc parece lidar com ele como se essa função fosse síncrona.

Comment: Obrigado a todos. Vander, vc me lembrou do assincronismo, verdade, quero sincrono. vou dar uma olhada nisso. Obrigado. Eu estava lendo q o getJSON por natureza é sempre ASSINCRONO.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado a todos, consegui resolver com a ajuda de vocês.
foi so mudar para sincrono e tudo ficou mais facil.
Abraços

```
function detailObs(index, row) {
  var html = [];
  if(row['valor'] != null) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/filas/slctTipo',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      async: false,
      success: function(retorno){
        $.each(retorno, function(key, val){
          if(row['valor'] == val.id) 
            html.push('<ul><li>' + val.tipo + '</li></ul>')
        })
      }
    })
  } else {
    html.push('<p style="text-align:center"><b>  Sem registro </p>')
  }
  return html.join('')
}
```